# Using User Control in Master Page - Need Focus

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the scenario:

I have a Master Page,
In the Master Page I have a user control
In the User Control there is a code that looks like this

```
<div>
<a id="p1" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="Img" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" Style="position:relative;
        bottom: 0px;" /></a> -<a id="p2" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="lblRate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            Rates</a>
 </div>
```

Now, when the user clicks on "Rates" it should focus on an item that is another User Control back in the Master Page.

How can I do this?, this is existing code and can not modify the current structure but **what is currently happening is that when "Rates" is clicked** it postsback with a parameter **goto=rates** but doesnt do anything.. I need to make so that when it is clicked it focuses on another UserControl in the Master Page. (but this "Rates" link is User Control too)

I tried in my Master Page the following

```
if(!Page.Postback)
{
   if(Request.Params["goto"] == "rates"){ 
    uControl.Focus(); 
    }
}
```

No luck, please help :(

So to recap:

MasterPage has UserControl -> UserControl has a link that postsback with parameter goto=rates -> back in the MasterPage I need to focus the screen on another UserControl.

I tried to be as clear as I could

Thank you

Comment: Why are you doing it only when the request is not a post back?

Comment: I tried with the options suggested below, I removed the !Postback still does not focus

Comment: well the control is Called uControl and it contains the code i posted on the first part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not all controls supports focus like this. for your user control, you may need build javascript to setup focus.

Comment: How do I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: get the real element you want to focus on and call focus(). here is the link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

Comment: You can not use serverside focus to set focus on label and image. Try javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a not opperator where you should.  You should change `if(!Page.Postback)` to `if(Page.Postback)`.

Comment: Yes did that too removed if(!IsPostBack)